# php - simple message posting / getting back as JSON object for Android app

Tags: php, android, json, message

I'm working with java android and absolutely have zero knowledge of php.
I know how to send data to php or receive data in JSON in android, but got zero knowledge about php.

All I need is a simple "message board" - no discussion threads, only name, message and time when it was posted - I send it from android app to php, it should store it and then when app asks - it should give me JSON data back with all the name/message/time of messages that there are on the server.

Well, I don't know if it's a simple task or not. The way I see it - it should be simple but once again I don't know php -maybe it's a 1000 lines code) but I really want that feature in my app :) if it's not simple and it needs a lot of code - just say so :) if there's not too much code - please help me with that. 
I tried to google it - there are only solutions for large scale message boards, etc
Thank you

Comment: This means you need to have a database of some form to store these values, then you send the request to the `PHP` which will in turn query the database for your `Message Board` data and within the `PHP` you can parse the results as `JSON` to return them to your android app.

Comment: If you do not know PHP why do you need to write the back in PHP? Why not in Java, for example?

Comment: kabuto178 , well, the way I see it - server can hold some data for me -  I send it with HttpClient class from the app. So as I suppose (I don't know), php script should process my data sent and store it somewhere and send me back all the messages' data as JSON?

Comment: m4t1t0 is it possible? I need that users of my app could send messages on the wall with no thread/response or anything - just one-way post. As far as I know it is done with php?

Comment: please read this link.i hope its useful for you.
[http://androidexample.com/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123]

Comment: @user2234594 : what do you mean `store it somewhere`? I think @kabuto178 saying database is the something you want. As where else can you store data?